# Vuex internal dependencies

Tags: vue.js, dependencies, action, vuex, mutation

What is the best practice to solve such situation:

1. state of one vuex component depends on state of another
2. this refresh of the first component must be done via action (asynchronous operations)

Now I do it from the visual vue component, in the place, where mutation of the second vuex component is commited, after the commitment. But it seems to me not nice practice to place vuex internal dependencies in visual components. How is it possible to place dependencies logic in vuex code?